# Passing variable to the view from zend form using AJAX load

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, zend-form

controller:

```
public function searchAction()
{  
    $form = new Application_Form_Search;
    $k = $form->getValue('keyword');
    $car    = new Application_Model_Car();
    $mapper  = new Application_Model_CarMapper();
    $this->view->cars = $mapper->search($keyword);
}
```

form

```
<?php
class Application_Form_Search extends Zend_Form {

    public function init(){
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElement('text', 'keyword', array(
            'required'   => true,      
            'label'      => 'Keyword:'
        ));

        $this->addElement('button', 'submit', array(
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,                
            'label'    => 'Search'
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

original view page

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#submit").click(function(){
      $("#main").load('/cars/search'); 
     });  
  });
```

Here I am trying to return the search view at the "id=main" section in the original view page by using `.load()`

In the search view, `<?=$this->keyword?>` is showing null
it seems like there's problem fetching the keyword field from the form

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to set the second variable of .load to send the data. At present you aren't sending the data to the .load function

so it would be more like this. This is assuming that you have id of keyword

```
$("#main").load('/cars/search', {'keyword':$('input#keyword').val()});
```

or you could use

```
$("#main").load('/cars/search', {'keyword':$('[name="keyword"]').val()});
```

Please see
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Also remember to escape the value so people can't send malicious code through your form.

Hope that helps